# Android Master/Detail Flow

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'd like to have a screen before entering the Master/Detail flow, but I'm not sure how to transition.  What I'm looking for is a screen that has some input to connect to a server, and upon connecting you are brought to the master detail view.  I've already finished the connecting part, but how would I fit these two together?

Comment: Are you asking for a code or a design approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

is the usual rutine to transitioning between activities